# Proving $A=U_{r}S_{r}V_{r}^{T}$ for a Full SVD

Tags: linear-algebra, numerical-linear-algebra, svd

Given the full SVD decomposition of a rank $r$ matrix $A\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$, how can we show that $A=U_{r}S_{r}V_{r}^{T}$ where $U\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times m}$, $V\in\mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, and $S\in\mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$?

Comment: Show that $Ax = U_r S_r V_t^Tx$ for all $x$. I am not kidding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that :
\begin{align*}
A&=U S V^{T}=\left[U_{r} \mid U_{m-r}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c|c}
S_{r} & 0_{r, n-r} \\
\hline 0_{m-r, r} & 0_{m-r, n-r}
\end{array}\right]\left[\begin{array}{c}
V_{r}^{T} \\
\hline V_{n-r}^{T}
\end{array}\right]=\left[U_{r} \mid U_{m-r}\right]\left[\frac{S_{r} V_{r}^{T}}{0_{m-r, n}}\right]\\
&=U_{r} S_{r} V_{r}^{T}
\end{align*}